# Google analytics not showing Real time data

Tags: android

I had integrated Google analytics in my android application but on dashboard of GA it is not showing any user. please help me where i am getting wrong.

I am writing code as below

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
{

tracker=GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

tracker.startNewSession(TRACKER_ID,20,this);
```

//also want to know what is this second parameter is used for. i am using 20 sec but I dont why to use that parameter.As written in GA it automatic dispatch  after 20 sec is it right?

```
tracker.trackPageView("MyPage");

}

@Override
    public void onDestroy()
{

    super.onDestroy();
    tracker.stopSession();  
}
```

and there are multiple activities in my application using same type of code in all activities.

still not coming any data on GA. Completed 24 hours after integrated the GA in my app. please help why GA data is not coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have facing problem to integrate google analytics in your app not showing real time data .In google analytics make profile for your website . it is same as for app . gives you same UA-xxxxxxxx-1 and then integrate this in your app same as [Google Analytics integration in Android app](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide)

It worked for me , I hope this will help you.

Comment: i just created analytics account for web not for app and it worked for me ...thanks.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, is real-time analytics for mobile sdks reliable?

Answer (score 0):

// Start the tracker in manual dispatch mode...

```
tracker.startNewSession(Tracker_Id, MainActivity.this);
```

You need to use `tracker.dispatch();` for dispatch the data on Google Analytical after track the pageView.

Comment: but why i can not use this tracker.startNewSession(TRACKER_ID,20,this);     instead of manual starting.

Answer (score 0):

On your Google Analytics you must Activate the Property MObile App, its 2 different Views, the mobile and the Web, although they share the same ID